# BigQuery giving unrecognized error for table name

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, google-analytics, inner-join

```
SELECT
    employees.name AS employee_name,
    employees.role AS employee_role,
    departments.name AS departments_name
FROM
  `my-project-41566-361115.employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN `my-project-41566-361115.employee_data.departments`
ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Why did I get a BigQuery "unrecognized error for table name" error?

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

Use `[` `]` quotation:

```
SELECT
employees.name AS employee_name,
employees.role AS employee_role,
departments.name AS departments_name
FROM [my-project-41566-361115].[employee_data].[employees]
INNER JOIN [my-project-41566-361115].[employee_data].[departments]
ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

Comment: Why did you undo my format corrections?